# How to get objects' index in a Java List

Tags: java, arraylist, json

I'm trying to add  data into array list. in this result

```
[{Store={id_store=2, namestore=Kupat Tahu Singaparna , product=[{id_product=1, price=100000, quantity=1}]}}]
```

you could use this code:

```
static ArrayList Storecart = new ArrayList(); 
LinkedHashMap store = new LinkedHashMap();
LinkedHashMap storeitem = new LinkedHashMap();
LinkedHashMap listproduct = new LinkedHashMap();
ArrayList prdct = new ArrayList(); 

storeitem.put("id_store",id_store);
storeitem.put("namestore",namestr ); 
listproduct.put("id_product", id_prodt);
listproduct.put("price",priced); 
listproduct.put("quantity", quantity); 

prdct.add(listproduct); 
storeitem.put("product", prdct);
store.put("Store", storeitem);
Storecart.add(store);
```

I need to get the index of an object in the array list. The problem is, I can't looping array list for "get object Store, and object product" and find every index.. what will be the best & efficient solution ?

Comment: Why are you using `Map`s here, when you should be writing a class to hold this data?  And _why_ can't you loop through the `ArrayList`?  (And finally, why aren't you using generics, which would make your code significantly more readable?)

Comment: looking for List.indexOf(Object) ??

Comment: [`ArrayList` has an `indexOf` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: Note that the indexOf method probably still iterates through the array, so if the concern is around performance the indexOf operator probably won't buy you anything. The sentiment of the comments is good -- always try to choose your data structures to support your requirements, rather than finding a way to compensate for the wrong data structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could use List.indexOf(), as others have suggested:

[Java List API: indexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29)

If you plan on doing this a lot, then presumably you have a handle on your Object reference.  So, you could just extend/wrap the Object you want the index of to keep track of its own index.  Specifically, you could assign the Object its index based on the order you first encounter it or something.  The order of the Object in the Collection would then be irrelevant.

I suppose you could also use a Map as yet another possibility.  Then only work with the Map instead of an ArrayList.

Bottom-line: if you're doing a lot of "indexOf()" requests, then the ArrayList may not be the best container for your data.